# Java: read hex digit from file as byte array, then convert byte array back to hex string

Tags: java, string, hex, arrays

The Java code I am working on read hex digits from a file as byte array, and my job is to convert the byte array back to hex strings. For simplicity, I use a hex digit string and convert it to byte array:

```
String hexString = "333112";
byte[] byteArray = hexString.getBytes(); // this is equivalent to what I got from reading files containing hex string
```

I then use the following method to convert the byte array back to hex string (as copied from another SO thread)

```
static final char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    public static String getHex(byte[] raw) {

        if ( raw == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        char[] hexChars = new char[raw.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < raw.length; j++ ) {
            int v = raw[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }


String originalHexStr = getHex(byteArray);
System.out.println(originalHexStr);
```

However, the above print statement outputs this: `333333313132`, which is not the same as the original hex String `333112`. So I must be missing something obvious. Thanks for help!

Comment: String.getBytes() is not a converter from ASCII-Hex to binary bytes. The character '3' is equivalent to 0x33, etc.

Comment: `int v = (raw[j] - '0') & 0xFF;`